# Modify Code - Select Certain Columns onEdit. Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot get this code to do what I am trying to get it to do. If there is a TRUE in Column 10 then run the Sort Query on SendToTotalSales - NOT ONLINERELOCATION

```
function MoveDonations(e) {
var sh=e.range.getSheet();
if(sh.getName()!='ONLINERELOCATION')return
if(e.range.columnStart==10 && e.value=="TRUE") {

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,????).setFormula('=SORT(QUERY(ONLINERELOCATION!A2:J,"SELECT A, 
F, G, D",0))'); 

}
//var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("SendToTotalSales");
//var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
//sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).copyTo(trg);
}
```

I am hoping I was Close !

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your title, it seems that you want to do `Select Certain Columns onEdit.`. But in your question, it seems that you want to do `If there is a TRUE in Column 10 then run the Sort Query on SendToTotalSales`. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your current issue and goal?

Comment: Tanaike-列10 = trueの場合、SendToTotalSalesという名前のタブで並べ替えクエリを実行したい

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to put the formula of `'=SORT(QUERY(ONLINERELOCATION!A2:J,"SELECT A, F, G, D",0))'` at the sheet of `SendToTotalSales`, when `MoveDonations` is run by the OnEdit event trigger, you want to modify to `e.source.getSheetByName("SendToTotalSales").getRange(row,????).setFormula(###)`. But from your question, I'm not sure where range you want to put the formula. I apologize for this.

Comment: Tanaike-列10のチェックボックスをオンにすると、並べ替えクエリはA、F、D、G列をSendToTotalSalesにエクスポートする必要があります

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor understanding. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect?

Comment: Tanaike - please see link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFeKjGOvDaWDU3CuPKhMEQS45K9bQK5pmQa5ZnhnfJ4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - Thank you once again for your help. Code worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When the checkbox of the column "J" in the sheet of `ONLINERELOCATION` is checked, you want to copy the values of the columns "A,D,F,G" to the sheet of `SendToTotalSales` as "A,F,G,D".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

In this case, you can also use the simple OnEdit event trigger (`onEdit(e)`).

```
function MoveDonations(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "ONLINERELOCATION" && range.columnStart == 10 && range.columnEnd == 10 && range.rowStart >= 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var [[a,,,d,,f,g]] = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, 7).getValues();
    e.source.getSheetByName("SendToTotalSales").appendRow([a, f, g, d]);
  }
}
```

- In order to run the script, please check the checkbox of the column "J" in the sheet of `ONLINERELOCATION`. By this, the values of the row are copied to `SendToTotalSales`.

#### Note:

- I think that when `'=SORT(QUERY(ONLINERELOCATION!A2:J,"SELECT A, F, G, D",0))'` is used, all values are put. So I proposed above script.
- And I'm not sure whether the duplicate process is required for your situation.